# Context-Free Grammar from Samples

Tags: tools, fuzzing

Is there a tool available that will generate a grammar from a corpus of sample inputs, similar to what [HotFuzz](http://hotfuzz.sourceforge.net/) does for network protocols?

For example, given a collection of MP3 files, I'm looking for a tool that would generate a BNF grammar to describe the format of MP3.

Answer (score 3):

I haven't used either, but [Peach Fuzzer](http://peachfuzzer.com/), on which HotFuzz is based, has a "Peach Fuzz Bang" GUI for fuzzing files.

Keep in mind, though, that fuzzers try to generate *invalid* inputs that crash a program, not determine the exact grammar that describes all valid input.

Furthermore, strictly speaking, it isn't mathematically possible to do what you're asking. If a computer could comprehensively learn a language merely by reading text in that language, then machine translation would be a solved problem. (This is a slightly poor analogy since [not all human languages are context-free](http://www.eecs.harvard.edu/~shieber/Biblio/Papers/shieber85.pdf), but the idea is clear.)

Comment: I'm probably showing my ignorance, but it doesn't _seem_ like it should be that impossible of a problem, right?  Given a bunch of sample data, I should be able to diff and determine the general structure (e.g. 4-byte header that stays the same, followed by a 4-byte int, maybe a NULL-terminated string follows, etc).  Why would doing that be impossible?

Comment: @mrduclaw: It's just the title of your question that's the impossibly general part, and is the subject of [research](http://aclweb.org/anthology-new/O/O06/O06-1004.pdf). If you just want to figure out the common header structure of a set of binary files, see [this SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/492751/tools-to-help-reverse-engineer-binary-file-formats), which has some good answers.

Comment: Great paper suggestion, seems far from impossible, thanks!

Comment: [Angluin's paper on L*](http://www.cse.iitk.ac.in/users/chitti/thesis/references/learningRegSetsFromQueriesAndCounterExamples.pdf) gives a proof that grammar inference can be achieved in polynomial time if an oracle is available to answer membership queries. [This paper](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/summary?doi=10.1.1.53.5084) includes descriptions and discussion of performance of other algorithms for grammar inference. An approach as used by [Polyglot](http://repository.cmu.edu/cgi/viewcontent.cgi?article=1007&context=ece) might scale better, though.

Comment: Here are some papers about a technique to derive a context free grammar based on the binary analysis of the polymorphic engine of a virus [[1](http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/ielx5/6044613/6059944/06059958.pdf?tp=&arnumber=6059958&isnumber=6059944),[2](http://www.labri.fr/perso/tabary/publis/polysigns.pdf),[3](http://www.labri.fr/perso/tabary/publis/nss2011-slides.pdf)]. I am not sure it is really relevant here... But, maybe you can find some use of it.